# Rule Policy not updating message?

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2010

I have built a schema, an orchestration with a receive port that receives messages of that type, and passes the message to a business rule.  The business rule policy updates an element in the message with a true or false based on the rule.  I have a scope shape with a call rule shape inside it.  The call rule shape passes the message to the rule, and then I have a send shape which sends the message to a send port.  I've tested the rule policy and it works fine, but when I drop a file, the orchestration processes it and output a file which should have an updated value from the rule policy, however the output file is always the same as the input file.  I know messages are immutable, so how shoudl I be getting a value out of the BR, and constructing a new message with it?

Answer (score 1):

The Call Rules shape will construct the new message, so it sounds like your rule may not be firing.  Have you enabled tracking on the policy?  See link for instructions:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa995589(BTS.10).aspx

Comment: Make sure you enable debugging per instructions above so you can find out what rules and code is executing properly.  9 times out of 10, the rule is not firing due to criteria not being met.